# Databases with row/document based write locks

Tags: mongodb, concurrency, locking, nosql

Can you suggest a database for storage of files(1KB-2GB) which supports single document write locks. I was initially using MongoDB but got really disappointed when I found out that the locks are database based, which means that if a single user is uploading a file, all other users will have to wait for the write lock to be released.

Comment: did you actually see locks limit the throughput of your application or are you assuming that they will?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at the TukoMX for MongoDB. It replaces the storage engine of MongoDB and they have document locking instead of DB-scope locking.
http://www.tokutek.com/products/tokumx-for-mongodb/

Comment: Sounds amazing on paper and provides document level locking. Definitely going to try it out. Thanks for the link!